# Azure Function app - using Visual studio code upload only one function out of many function apps from local

Tags: azure-functions

I am using Visual studio code for development, how I can upload only one Azure Function app using Visual studio code out of function apps from local. For now whenever I deploy all function apps are uploaded to Function app in Cloud, also its over-writting any existing functions.

Need details on

1. How to upload only 1 or selected function apps from local to Azure cloud Function app
2. How to download function app from Azure cloud to local Visual studio code.

Thanks in advance for your guidence.

Comment: when you Publish from VS, all the public functions decorated with FunctionName[] attribute will be treated as functions. You can place some compile time flag conditions to avoid certain functions to be published. The 2nd part of your question does not make sense, what are you expecting?

Comment: I assumed you were using C#, if so, you can refer this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation)  to know how to use compile time preprocessing checks.

Comment: @SSR, Please clarify my doubt on your 1st question. Look at this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/mcdxAWE.png), are you having multiple function apps locally like this in Visual studio Code. If yes, are you asking how to deploy selected function app to azure function?

Answer (score 2):

> 2. How to download function app from Azure cloud to local Visual studio code.

**If you created your functions by using the editor in the Azure portal, you can download your existing function app project as a .zip file in one of these ways:**

**From the Azure portal:**

1. In the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) > Go to your function app > **Overview**  tab > click the option **Download app content** > Select your download options > Next is to select  **Download** option.

[image]
You can take any option in the download window. Here I taken **Content and Visual Studio Project**
[image]

After extracting the zip file, the project will be like:
[image]

The downloaded .zip file is in the correct format to be republished to your function app by using .zip push deployment. The portal download can also add the files needed to open your function app directly in Visual Studio or Visual Studio code.

- **Using REST APIs:**

  Use the following deployment GET API to download the files from your  `<function_app>`  project:

  HTTPCopy

  ```
  https://<function_app>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/
  ```

  Including  `/site/wwwroot/`  makes sure your zip file includes only the function app project files and not the entire site. If you are not already signed in to Azure, you will be asked to do so.

#### Updated Answer:

I tried with the python Azure Function App to download its content. ***Download content*** is disabled for python function application but there is an option called ***publish profile*** > Download It and Open in Notepad++ for clear view.

[image]

Download and Install the [***WInSCP***](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php) and paste your endpoint URL looks `ftps://prod-url-name.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot`

And enter the ***username*** and ***password*** given in ***publish profile*** text file, but not with your Microsoft account credentials or other creds.

[image]

OR
Instead of getting the URL, username and password from publish content, you can see it in your Azure portal > function app > Deployment center:

[image]

In WinSCP, you can hit on Login after entering the credentials, then it shows the function app content to download.

#### To exclude specific functions from deploying to Azure:

The way to exclude the files during deploying from VS Code to azure is using the `.funcignore` file which has the same semantics as `.gitignore` and only takes effect in publishing.

**References**:

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/341#issuecomment-364310826
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#download-your-function-app-files

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a separate folder in local for each function or group of functions that you want to be part of specific Azure function. Use 'New Window' option in 'vscode' and locate the new folder you created(this allows local workspace to be scoped to that particular folder). Make sure you create all the required functions in the new folder. Then you can only upload that particular function or group of functions.